# How to dynamically pass a parameter in the get in method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spotify

In the network tab, I send the query 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?limit=14&market=US&offset=5&q=abba&type=track,artist'

It does not work: how to set the query to be in that order:
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=mmm&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&o

'q' should be after search?

```
 getArtists(query) {
   const params = {
        type: 'track,artist',
        market: 'US',
        limit: 14,
        offset: 5
    };

    if (typeof query === 'string') {
        params.q = query;
    }

    console.log(params) 

    return this.$http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search", { 
params }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function myError(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
  };

getArtists('Abba');
```

Comment: Is it `typeof(query)`?

Comment: The order of parameters is irrelevant.

Comment: Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Where I can put token auth? Is it any simple way?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale No parentheses. `typeof` is an operator, not a function. [MDN's docs for `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a auhtorization error when trying your apis.

```
{
"error": {
"status": 401,
"message": "No token provided"
}
}
```

You need to provide the authorization token in the header to fix this.

```
getArtists(query) {
let params = {
    q: query,
    type: 'track,artist',
    market: 'US',
    limit: 14,
    offset: 5
};

if (typeof query !== 'string') {
    delete params.q;
}

console.log(params) 

return this.$http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search", {headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer <AUTHORIZATION TOKEN>}, 
params }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}, function myError(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
};
```

If you don't have it yet, check out the process here : https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getArtists(query) {
   let params = {
        q: query,
        type: 'track,artist',
        market: 'US',
        limit: 14,
        offset: 5
    };

    if (typeof query !== 'string') {
        delete params.q;
    }

    console.log(params) 

    return this.$http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search", { 
params }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function myError(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
  };
```

Comment: I generate 0Auth token, but it doesn't work. "message": "No token provided"

Comment: try with `let` instead of `const`

Comment: Answers consisting of "Try this" followed by uncommented code are more often downvoted, and less often upvoted, than questions which explain how and why the code is different.

Comment: this same problem: "message": "No token provided". When I have example "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist" it works. But I have change 'q' dynamicly